# Append multiple column values into single column by adding column values below in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, merge

Am having a datattable like below with 3 columns name,favourite1 and 2.

```
Name   Favourite1   Favourite2

xxx     Eating       Cricket
yyy     Books        Music
```

my expected output is

```
Name   Favourites     

xxx    Eating        
yyy    Books         
xxx    Cricket
yyy    Music
```

how to make it ... :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in C#. The `Merge` function is used to merge the two data tables. The expected output will be in `fav1` datatable.

```
DataTable fav1;
fav1= ThreeColumntable.Copy();
fav1.Columns.Remove("Favourite2");
fav1.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Favourites";

DataTable fav2;
fav2= ThreeColumntable.Copy();
fav2.Columns.Remove("Favourite1");
fav2.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Favourites";

fav1.Merge(fav2);
```

Comment: its okie but how to make the result in datatable.. @kumar

Comment: @Arshad: I have update the result, used merge function to get the result in datatable. Reply the status.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Name, unpvt.Favourites  from 
(select * from @tbl) tbl
unpivot (Favourites For fields in (Favorite1, Favorite2)) as unpvt
```

@tbl - is your table.